# shifting bits of input in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a 4-bit input A that I want to shift left and right. I was wondering if it's possible to shift just the input instead of assigning the shifted value to an output. For example I can do B = A<<1 but I don't want to make a new variable.
can the input itself be shifted so I can display it once I simulate it?

Comment: Think hardware not software.  You are not creating a new variable, you are passing a new value along to the next bit of hardware, so you *must* have "copy and modify"

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change the input value from inside the module, but you can shift it when you connect to the port at the level above:

```
module foo (A);

  input [3:0] A;

endmodule

module tb;

  wire [3:0] signal = 4'b0101;
  foo u_foo (.A(signal << 1));

endmodule
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. IN that case if I want to keep everything within a single module I will have to assign shifted A to an output.